# Choosing OS from startup - too many options

Tags: dual-boot, startup

I recently installed Linux Mint alongside my Windows 10, and after using boot-repair in Linux, now I can choose between my 2 operating systems. However, there are multiple choices on the start-up menu now that I don't want since other people might use my computer and accidentally enter system setup or other pathways and change something in the process. How can I get rid of all options except the 2 operating systems?

Comment: Questions on other distributions should be asked at Unix & Linux StackExchange. Oh, and to your question, please use a tool like grub-customizer and remove whatever entries you don't want.

Comment: set the grub_timeout = 0 in /etc/default/grub.  Then run update_grub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the grub.cfg. It is located in

```
/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

This file is laid out in an xml format. Looking at it you can gain an intuition as to how you would like it modified. I recommend commenting out the entries you dont want by putting # at the start of all lines relevant to the entry. Because you are new to this interface, I am showing you gedit, it works like a supercharged Windows Notepad.

I recommend backing up your grub file with the first command.

```
$sudo cp /boot/grub2/grub.cfg ~/grub.cfg.bak    
$sudo gedit /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Now you can modify at will, because you have root permissions.

In the event you want to undo your modifications

```
$sudo update-grub
```

will automatically detect,and setup all detected bootable partitions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Whatever changes that I make are reversed when I run the update-grub command. Maybe I should use a different command for the second step?

Comment: Repeat the above, but try it without the update-grub my mistake.

Comment: Any update to kernel or grub will auto run the update-grub and erase your changes. At top of file it says not to edit. It is rebuilt from grub scripts & configuration file. But you can turn off some scripts and create your own 40_custom that only has the entries you want. Then the auto update only includes your custom entries. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen I prefer learning to manually edit grub files over grub-customizer, it adds its own scripts and can create issues. But for those who do not want to learn & want an easy gui way it does usually work.